# Is there a approach to get instant onlineMeeting in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I need to get teams online meetings or teams calls including instant meetings or calls. Are there some approaches to do this? I found next methods https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http for getting meetings or calls by id, join url (for meetings) etc. But how can I get these ids/urls etc including instant (not only scheduled) meetings?